# How to insert a sub list page after an existing list page in Windows App Studio?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store-apps, microsoft-appstudio

I am exploring Windows app studio , I want to create an app that will display a list of items by category, and each category must have a subcategory, but it looks like that the template does not have subcategories build in.  I have choosed "My Products Catalog" template. How to add a new  list page after  the existing list page? Should I choose a different template?

The click order  must be like this:
1st Category> subcategory> detail page

A screenshot of the windows app studio template:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows App studio currently does not support two level navigation within one section. You can setup something similar adding a "Menu" section for each category. In the menu you can add some sub-sections that can map to your sub-categories.